# Can't run React Native App on Expo CLI simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I created a React Native application using the command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

After creating the project I try to run in a simulator with the command:

```
yarn ios
```

The app runs correctly but the terminal shows that it is opening on an iPhone 8, however the simulator opens on an iPhone 13 and the application never starts, I also start a simulator choosing an iPhone 8 as a device but the app does not start there either.

[image]

Comment: focus the simulator and try interacting with it - open the settings app or something. this may result in the prompt about opening the Expo Go to appear. this is a quirk of the ios simulator

Answer (score 0):

The [React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-simulator-ios#specifying-a-device) recommend using the --simulator flag with react-native run-ios:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro Max”
```

If you run into (like I did):

```
command not found: react-native
```

Try running the script for iOS in your app’s package.json (often it’s ios):

```
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro Max”
```

In theory npm should work also, but I didn’t have any luck. Your mileage may vary:

```
npm run ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro Max”
```

**List Available Devices**

List available iOS devices:

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

Available devices for iOS `13.3` on my machine:

```
iPhone 8 (2FE6CAE2–4908–4464–884A-5DED11505CE4) (Shutdown)
iPhone 8 Plus (F2A473F7–1F48–48DB-A6A6–584253814AA6) (Shutdown)
iPhone X (8FC4167D-AC9C-4F90–825C-9FB7004D03BA) (Booted)
iPhone 11 (E7885A5A-0306–4243-A852–8E71A7B0A5CB) (Shutdown)
iPhone 11 Pro (13B1AF48-BDD5–4AD7–8D7C-F31F3CF97FF5) (Shutdown)
iPhone 11 Pro Max (9C3B2313–258B-4E79–86A3–275D6BB3D078) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (1A094DA7-A246–47B7–9716–5D8A9190C563) (Shutdown)
iPad (7th generation) (E0E0E252–5B96–4D2B-BD98–7D9ED79756AD) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (143BB411-E726–4048–98E5-F87F04DEDCC2) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) (14EFAE0F-C4D2–49E3-B501–633CB3E7DD00) (Shutdown)
iPad Air (3rd generation) (2797C8B5-E8FC-428A-AA4A-81F500153DDA) (Shutdown)
```

**Commands for Your Convenience**

Here are some commands with `yarn` that are ready-to-use for your convenience:

```
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone 8"
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone 8 Plus”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone X”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone 11"
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro Max”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPad Pro (9.7-inch)”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPad (7th generation)”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPad Pro (11-inch)”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPad Pro (12.9-inch)”
yarn ios --simulator=”iPad Air (3rd generation)”
```

**Note**

There is currently no way to set a default device for the Simulator.

Comment: please mark it as accepted if it helped. Thanks!